# Infinite sets and arithmetic progressions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $S\subset\mathbb N$ is infinite, prove that we can find $p,q\in\mathbb N$, such that either whenever $ n\equiv p\pmod q$, we have$$
n\in S
$$
or else whenever  $n\equiv p\pmod q$, we have $$
n\notin S.
$$

Comment: This is not a well-posed question. Do you mean there are $p,q\in\Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\in\Bbb N$ satisfying $n\equiv p\mod q$ $n\in S$? If so, that's false if $S$ is just infinite.

Comment: Yes,if $S$ is infinite,I want find $p,q$, but I'm not sure if this conclusion is correct.Can you give me a counter example.thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with set theory, and it is not really number theory either.

Comment: Sorry,I'm not sure how to classify really!

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Enumerate all pairs $(p,q)$ as $pair_1,pair_2,\dots$ Now build two disjoint sets $S$ and $T$ by stages. First, set $S_0=T_0=\emptyset$. Our construction will ensure that $S_0\subsetneq S_1\subsetneq S_2\subsetneq\dots$ and similarly with the $T_i$, while maintaining that $S_i, T_i$ are disjoint. At the end, we set $S=\bigcup_n S_n$ and $T=\bigcup_n T_n$ and note that, by construction, these sets are indeed disjoint. At stage $k$ we have $S_k,T_k$, the constructed sets so far, and consider $pair_k=(a,b)$. Find $n\ne m$, both large enough (larger than all elements in $S_k\cup T_k$) and congruent to $a$ mod $b$. Set $S_{k+1}=S_k\cup\{n\}$ and $T_{k+1}=T_k\cup\{m\}$.

The construction ensures that, for any $p,q$, both $S$ and its complement (that necessarily contains $T$) have elements congruent to $p$ mod $q$. This means that $S$ does not contain all these elements, but does not miss all of them either.

(By ensuring for instance that each pair is listed infinitely often, we may also arrange that both $S$ and $T$ meet each such congruence class in an infinite set.)